# If all 7's are replaced by the digit 6 , then the number of 6's in series 1,2,3,4.....99, 100 will be (options)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

As the title says.
The options available are:
(A) 31   (B) 32   (C) 33   (D)  none of these

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: How did you approach the problem, and what did you get?

Comment: It has to be an even number by symmetry

Comment: I got 38. $ $ $ $

Comment: @T_O: Is "none of these" an even number?

Comment: @TonyK yes apparently ;) Actually I didn't see the (D) option at first

Comment: There are 10 7's in the second position(of you write 01,02,03,... so you get 07,17,...,97.) and 10 7's in the first position(70,71,72,...,79). There are also the same number of 6's. Hence the answer is 40.

Comment: You probably only counted 66 and 77 for one, not two.

Comment: @Ross: but counted 67 and 76 for two, not one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** in the collection of all integers you write, 
every number with two digits is represented (plus 100).

solution:

hence, the number of 6s is the same as the number of 7s, that is $10+10 =20$ (then for each spot, as $100$ does not count).

Then the answer is $40$ (none of these).

Comment: You are counting 67, 76, 77 and 66 twice, I think.

Comment: not if 77 is twice in the resulting series, but you may be right. Actually, I think OP's question is not precise enough.

Comment: @Infinitum counting it twice *is* the point.

Comment: I do not agree: I don't know any firm definition of a number *series*, do you?

Comment: Ah, just realized. My bad.

Comment: and by the way, as 67 and 76 swap I think there is only the 77$\to$66 issue...

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

First, count the number of sixes in the series. We have 6, 16, 26, 36, ..., 96, as well as 60, 61, 62, ..., 69. Call this number $N$.

Second, cound the number of sevens in the series (in the same way, we have 7, 17, ..., 97, as well as 70, 71, ..., 79). Call this number $M$.

What would the sum $N+M$ be?

Comment: What do you mean don't count 66 twice? There are two 6 digits there so it adds 2 to the total.

Comment: @ThomasJRivera Oh, that's very bad of me, sorry, I'll edit.